# How to get jquery to work on WAMPserver?

Tags: html, wampserver

I am a jquery beginner and i have set up a wamp server to practice with html and jquery but i cant seem to get jquery to work. I have written a simple jquery code to test it.

This is my html code:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>


<body>

<div id= "wrapper">

<div class="intro"><BUTTON type="button">Who am I?</BUTTON></div>
<div class="contact"><BUTTON type="button">What am I?</BUTTON></div>
<div class="exp"><BUTTON type="button">Experience</BUTTON></div>

<div/> 
</body>
</html>
```

jquery.js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.intro').onClick(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut('slow', 300);
            });
        });
```

I am not sure if linking my jquery page correctly is the problem or the wamp server.

Answer (score 0):

First WAMPServer has little to do with jQuery code other than serving it to the browser, so its not a WAMPServer issue.

A couple of thing are wrong with the jquery code.

First there is no `onClick` function, you should be using `click` so

```
$('.intro').onClick(function(){
```

should become

```
$('.intro').click(function(){
```

Secondly this duration can be either `"slow"` denoting 600 milliseconds or a number of milliseconds. You have used both and thats not valid. In fact parameter 2 should be a callback function that will be run when the fade is completed. So

```
$(this).fadeOut('slow', 300);
```

becomes

```
$(this).fadeOut('slow', function(){
    // fade complete, 
    // you dont have to do anything in here if you dont want to
});
```

In fact you dont even have to use the second parameter if you are not going to do anything after the fade is complete. So it could be written as

```
$(this).fadeOut('slow');
```

So your script slightly recoded with all that in mind would be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.intro').click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut('slow', function(){
            // done
        });
    });
});
```

Or probably a better solution if you dont want to do anything when the fade is complete is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.intro').click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

And that should work as you expected.

Basically you need to look closer at the [JQuery manual](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) here

Comment: ok so I have followed your directions, and jquery still does not work.

html:
<!doctype html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="external" type="text/javascript" href="jquery.js">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
 <div class= "hide">
  <button type="button"> Hide Me!</button>
 </div>

</body>
</html>

jquery.js:
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.hide').click(function(){
  $(this).fadeOut('slow', function(){
   
  });
 });
});

Comment: I am also not using the wamp server anymore

Comment: I coded that up and tested it. It works. So your problem is someting else.

Comment: I fixed it by putting a <script src="jquery.js"></script> under the <head></head>tag. Thank you all for helping.

Comment: According to your question you already had that line in your `<head> section???????